# Preprocessing incoming mail with fetchmail/procmail/mutt

Tags: email, mutt, fetchmail, procmail

I use fetchmail->procmail->mutt programms to all my mail. Some of mail generated automatically and some people not smart enough, so I would like to reformat mail body with some script.

My best guess is that I should do it with procmail. But I found no such rule, best thing I found is possibility to pipe mail to programm. Of course, I can resend it with flag that no futher formatting needed, but it does not look like right solution.

EDIT: Just discovered `maildrop`. Maybe, it is simpler to do my task with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what sort of preprocessing you are looking for, but I'm guessing something like this.

```
:0fbw
| sed 's/\<grammer/grammar/g;s/definate/definite/g;s/sepera/separa/g'
```

If you want to edit headers such as Subject as well as the body, take out the `b`flag; but if your normalizations might change vital headers, perhaps you want to make it a bit more specific and/or robust.

Comment: Great! But I noticed, that my mail(utf-8 one) encoded with very long string of letters. I tried to just add text to end, but it do not work. So, I have to decode, format and code back. How can I decode?

Comment: There are various MIME encoding / decoding tools around.  For quoted-printable, `mimencode` used to be helpful, but it's by and large obsolete.  For base64, try the `base64` encoder / decoder from a reasonably recent `coreutils`.  If you are handy with a scripting language, there are MIME encoding and decoding libraries for Perl, Python, Lua, probably even TCL ... Maybe post a separate question with more details?  See also http://www.polarhome.com:793/~gustedt/normail.html